# Wi-Fi networks available but cannot connect to on 2008 MacBook Air

Tags: wifi, drivers, macbook, internet

I have an ancient 2008 MacBook Air laptop. I installed Elementary OS on it. Everything works fine, except Wi-Fi. It doesn't work out of the box. I attempted the advice [here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-no-wireless-network-ubuntu/), namely:

```
sudo apt remove broadcom-sta-dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

but that didn't work.

The default `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver also doesn't function.

Virtually every other distro worked for me by trying either of the two aforementioned solutions. I'm currently connecting with a Wi-Fi USB card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding pio=1 qos=0 on modprobe file by

```
 sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf
 echo "options b43 pio=1 qos=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf
```

reboot or reload b43 driver

Comment: Works like a lucky charm! Thank you! What I did was enter the first two lines of code in my question, then completed by entering your answer, and voilà!